# Wordpress pages and version control

Tags: wordpress, version-control, workflow

We are a software development company and are using Wordpress for static portion of the web site. Naturally, all our workflow is built around version control: multiple developers -> continious integration -> staging -> deployment.

Our challenge with integrating Wordpress into our workflow is that its database is stuck like a bone in the throat:  you cannot put it into the version control, easily roll back, promote from staging to production etc.

I am wondering what people do in similar situations? I would like to find a way to integrate WP into the development workflow and not the other way around :-)

**Clarification** we want to "develop" and test pages on the staging system and when ready then move them over to the production as part of the version upgrade process. We don't want to do full replication of the staging database to production.

Comment: Following [Jekyl from Github](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll), there have been a surge in use of static page generators. If I were to make this decision today, I would definitely go with this kind of solution. See [https://www.staticgen.com] for a good overview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a common question and one that I've worked on tackling. I've written some code to address these issues albeit the code's not ready for distribution. Basically the idea is to **create scripts to import the content and then version control the scripts**. *(Actually my approach uses a custom import/export format designed to be easy to hand-modify, but the idea is similar.)*

Anyway, there are some related questions over on StackOverflow's sister site [**WordPress Answers**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/):

- [**Questions tagged with the term *[staging]***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/staging)
- [**Questions tagged with the term *[deploy]***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deploy)

#### UPDATE

Per the clarification, this would probably be helpful too:

- [**Is there any way to draft a revision of a published page or post? What workarounds have you used?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/is-there-any-way-to-draft-a-revision-of-a-published-page-or-post-what-workaround/4398#4398)

Hope this helps.

-Mike

Comment: Thanks Mike, I have explored the "Wordpress Answers" but unfortunately didn't find the answer I was looking for so I figured I may have better chances with the developer's site. Wondering about your script -- are you version control data as well or only scripts? I need the former.

Comment: @Sasha O - So you asked your question over at WordPress Answers? Hmm, I didn't see your question over there, sorry. Am I version controlling _data_? Of course! That's what your question was about, otherwise I wouldn't have commented. There's also been a recent thread on wp-hackers list on the subject: http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-November/035959.html

Comment: I didn't ask the question, just looked at the existing questions and headed over to SO where I feel more confortable :-). Thanks for the pointer to wp-hackers; these guys seem to have slightly different problem though.

Comment: @Sasha O - Per your clarification, see my update.  Also, the active users at WordPress Answers are really dedicated to establishing WA as the best place to get answers about WordPress so maybe you can venture out and on over next time? After all, comfort zones are overrated. :)

Comment: thanks, your point is taken. I will post a question there. I will also follow up by email. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit the same problem.  For now we are using MySQL dump files to export/import database content, but it gets ugly with several people working on the database changes.

Since the team that works on the project is all internal and consists of just a few people, I'm thinking into the direction of locking the database dump file in VCS.  Subversion had this functionality built-in, but we are using git, which, I think, is conceptually opposite of any kind of locking.

Probably we'll have a workaround script with pre-commit hook to check for the existence of a lock file next to the dump.  The person who committed the lock file will be the only one allowed to commit the dump.  Once he finishes the work, he will need to commit the removal of the lock file.

It sounds ugly, I know. But I've thought about it for a while and don't see an elegant solution yet.

Answer (score -1):

If you're only using WordPress for static content, then any tool/methodology for version controlling databases should work - for example, work the mysql command line tools into your CI and deployment routines.